# Remote computer disk space report

Tags: powershell, report, diskspace

Here is my code for gathering disk space for all remote drives:

```
$Computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*windows*")}-Server $domain).dnshostname

$report1 = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -computer $computers -Credential $Creds | Select SystemName,DeviceID,VolumeName,@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.size/1gb)}},@{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.freespace/1gb)}}
```

And I get...

[image]

I want to arrange output so each machine is listed once on the left with drives in columns along the top:

[image]

Anyone know how?

Comment: build the listing as you are doing it now. then scan that listing to get the max number of drives per system so you can make the same props for all your systems. use `Group-Object` to group the rows by system name. last, iterate thru the grouping, build a PSCustomObject, send that to your collection ... and finally export that to a new csv.

Comment: You'll need to create a `[PsCustomObject]` with the various column headers as properties of the object.  That is, properties called 'Hostname', 'C-Size', 'D-Size', etc.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Lee_Daily's comment you can use the `Group-Object` cmdlet to create a unique group for every `SystemName`. Below example groups the objects in `$report1` by the `SystemName` property. `Group-Object` returns a `GroupInfo` object (or an array of `GroupInfo`'s ), where we select the content of the `Group` property (`SystemName` is also included in the `Group` property). The `Group` property is a HashSet that can be converted via `ConvertTo-Csv`.

```
 $peport1 | Group-Object SystemName | Select -ExpandProperty Group | ForEach-Object { $_ | ConvertTo-Csv  -NoTypeInformation }
```

You can replace `ConvertTo-Csv` with `Export-Csv`:

```
 $peport1 | Group-Object SystemName | Select -ExpandProperty Group | ForEach-Object { $_ | Export-Csv "repor1.csv"  -NoTypeInformation -Append }
```

`-Append` will append several rows, where each row is one entry of the `GroupInfo` array.

Documentation about the `Group-Object` cmdlet can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-6).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

here is a somewhat different approach. it requires that you wrap the following code in a scriptblock and then use `Invoke-Command` to run it on the target systems. if you can't get that working, please let me know ... [*grin*]

```
# if you have no locally mapped/subst-ed drive letters, remove this section
$SubstLocalDiskList = @(subst.exe |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_[0]
        })
$DiskList = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem |
    Where-Object {
        # read-only drives will show "0" used & "0" free 
        $_.Free -gt 0 -and
        $_.Used -gt 0 -and
        # if you have no locally mapped/subst-ed drive letters, remove this line
        $_.Name -notin $SubstLocalDiskList
        }

$FreeWarning_Pct = 10
$TempPropTable = [ordered]@{
    ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    }
foreach ($DL_Item in $DiskList)
    {
    $Size = $DL_Item.Used + $DL_Item.Free
    $SizeFree_Pct = [math]::Round($DL_Item.Free / $Size * 100, 2)
    if ($SizeFree_Pct -ge $FreeWarning_Pct)
        {
        $SFP_Status = 'OK'
        }
        else
        {
        $SFP_Status = '__ Low __'
        }

    $TempPropTable.Add('{0}_Drive' -f $DL_Item.Name, $DL_Item.Name)
    $TempPropTable.Add('{0}_Size_GB' -f $DL_Item.Name, [math]::Round($Size / 1GB, 2))
    $TempPropTable.Add('{0}_Free_Pct' -f $DL_Item.Name, $SizeFree_Pct)
    $TempPropTable.Add('{0}_SFP_Status' -f $DL_Item.Name, $SFP_Status)

    }

[PSCustomObject]$TempPropTable
```

truncated output for one system  ...

```
ComputerName C_Drive C_Size_GB C_Free_Pct C_SFP_Status D_Drive D_Size_GB D_Free_Pct D_SFP_Status E_Drive [*...snip...*] 
------------ ------- --------- ---------- ------------ ------- --------- ---------- ------------ ------- [*...snip...*] 
[MySysName]  C          931.41      79.22 OK           D          930.57      49.68 OK           E       [*...snip...*]
```